# How to Store Company Tree Structure to Local Storage Using js

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a tree structure on one HTML page where a user has created such a company tree structure as per his requirement.
But I want this structure data to save on local storage. where I can use this data on another HTML page and create the same structure there.

HTML Code.

```
<ul class="isParent" id="backend" onclick="myFunction(event)">
    <li><span class="caret-down edit" onclick="caret()">Ruhi Soya</span>
        <ul class="nested">
            <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit" onclick="caret()">Managing Director</span>
                <ul class="nested">
                    <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit" onclick="caret()">CEO</span>
                        <ul class="nested">
                            <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit" onclick="caret()">Production President</span>
                                <ul class="nested">
                                    <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit" onclick="caret()">Vice President</span>
                                        <ul class="nested">
                                            <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit"
                                                    onclick="caret()">Production Manager</span>
                                                <ul class="nested">
                                                    <li class="ifChild"> <span class="edit" id="edit">Managers</span></li>
                                                    <li class="ifChild"><span class="edit">Engineers</span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit" onclick="caret()">Project Manager</span>
                                        <ul class="nested">
                                            <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit" onclick="caret()">Engineer</span>
                                                <ul class="nested">
                                                    <li class="ifChild"> <span class="edit" id="edit">Contractors and Development Team</span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit" onclick="caret()">Marketing &amp; Sales ead President</span>
                                <ul class="nested">
                                    <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit" onclick="caret()">Marketing Head</span>
                                        <ul class="nested">
                                            <li class="ifChild"><span class="caret-down edit"> onclick="caret()">Regional Managers</span>
                                                <ul class="nested">
                                                    <li class="ifChild"> <span class="edit" id="edit">Area Managers</span></li>
                                                </ul>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="ifChild"><span class="edit">Sales Head</span></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="ifChild"><span class="edit">R&amp;D department</span></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to store this data created to local storage and create the same HTML to another HTML Div.

Comment: From what I understand the user did his/her part. What have you tried in order to do yours ?

Comment: as the user structure creates various bugs that come in the console as the null value of the parent element.

Comment: that was the most unclear thing i've read today :)  please be more clear. What have you tried to do in order to solve your problem and what errors did you encounter ?

Answer (score 0):

To save you could do:

```
localStorage.setItem('my-saved-content', document.getElementById('backend').innerHTML);
```

and to restore the saved information into an element on the other page:

```
document.getElementById('some-id').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('my-saved-content')
```